# How can I use a second nginx web app (swizzin) alongside virtualmin nginx site?

Tags: nginx, webserver, webmin

I have a goal of using my VPS for web host and seedbox. I cant figure out a way to get it to work with it. Currently every subdomain (including the one I configured swizzin to use) goes straight to the Virtualmin "under construction" page.

Could anyone help me out (with detailed instructions because i'm very bad at this). I have tried some suggestions of reverse proxy and upstream but was unable to get it to work.

Currently at 4 days of trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes, yes. After few days of struggle, I've got working Virtualmin and swizzin on one VPS.
First, you have to install Virtualmin with nginx support

```
https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/nginx
```

Then, install swizzin

```
bash <(curl -sL git.io/swizzin) && . ~/.bashrc
```

Install swizzin panel from gui or terminal

```
box install panel
```

And install letsencrypt for your domain

```
box install letsencrypt
```

And point your domain for example my.domain.com

Edit your nginx default

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

A put there

```
server {
server_name my.domain.com;
listen x.x.x.x;

client_max_body_size 40M;
server_tokens off;
root /srv/;

include /etc/nginx/apps/*;

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}

location /.well-known {
alias /srv/.well-known;
allow all;
default_type "text/plain";
autoindex    on;
}

# SSL configuration
server {
server_name my.domain.com;
listen x.x.x.x:xssl;

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.domain.com/key.pem;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
client_max_body_size 40M;
server_tokens off;
root /srv/;

include /etc/nginx/apps/*;

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

You should have working swizzin alongside Virtualmin.